# upgrading GNU libc (Debian Sid)

Tags: debian, upgrade, glibc

I'm running Debian/Sid/x86-64 on my desktop (mostly for development tasks). Current kernel is Debian 4.12.13

I'm quite interested by the latest features of [GNU libc 2.26](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2017-08/msg00010.html)

The current `libc` on my system is:

```
% /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 
GNU C Library (Debian GLIBC 2.24-17) stable release version 2.24, 
                 by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 6.4.0 20170820.
Available extensions:
    crypt add-on version 2.1 by Michael Glad and others
    GNU Libidn by Simon Josefsson
    Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
    BIND-8.2.3-T5B
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.debian.org/Bugs/>.
```

Is it unreasonable to upgrade it from the latest GNU sources?

I do know that libc is the cornerstone of most of my Linux distribution... I am too lame to setup a `chroot`-ed environment.

In practice, can I upgrade my `libc` without risking to break most of my system?

<sup>(I could afford to have a few obscure utilities not working after that, but I don't want to break all my system and have to re-install it)</sup>

In the past, I did upgrade my kernel without harm (to the latest one on [kernel.org](http://kernel.org/)). Would upgrading `libc` be likewise, or are there some naughty things likely to happen? Would going back be as simple as booting some kernel with `init=/bin/sash` and running a few commands (probably some `mv` then `ln -s` then `ldconfig`) ??

Comment: To set up a chrooted environment: `mkdir /playground; debootstrap sid /playground; mount --bind /dev /playground/dev; chroot /playground`, inside the chroot also a `mount /proc; mount sys /sys -t sysfs`

Comment: But then I won't be able to use most commands without practically reinstalling a Debian in that chroot

Comment: If you are playing with glibc recompilation, some `apt-get` really shouldn't be a big challenge...